# Password SHA512 x twice

Tags: mongodb, passwords, md5, sha

Ok, I am using MongoDB for my database, I want to know can I store this type of passwords in mongoDB

This is what my password gets saved as, Does anyone know if this password can be hacked?

```
æýÛ¯'éÀP‡ÙÏß¼„Šg€ÝÜ-…eÒ$T¨(OKñÅ£ÌùÚJÕµÔ¤D4#—)g½Ð¸èËæVêæ#¥
```

Comment: you should work at linkedin :)

Comment: If you want feedback on your password encryption you need to provide more than the hashed password. E.g. explain how you hash it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every password can ultimately be hacked so-to-speak.

Remember hashing and encryption are two different things -> http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function & http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salted_hash.

Hashing is a one-way function so typically what attackers do is run through a bunch of passwords in a wordlist, hash them and search for a match against the hashed password that they've stolen. The longer and more complex your password along with hashing the password with a random salt, then the harder it is to, as you say, hack the password.

If you want to learn more about passwords, check out this link - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/.

Here's information from the MongoDB website on security and authentication -  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-ChangingPasswords

This type of question is more suited to http://security.stackexchange.com where there's a lot of discussion about the recent the LinkedIn and LastFM password issues.